# How can I see what Wikipedia pages link to my website?

Tags: links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I see what pages on the internet link to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/how-do-i-see-what-pages-on-the-internet-link-to-my-site)

According to webworth.info, my website is linked to within Wikipedia.

Where in the world is that reference found for my domain and how would you find it?

Comment: I can't see that. webworth.info only states that it has one link in google. Where did you get the wikipedia info?

Comment: There was a section for the health of the website: And it said "bytecode.ca" is linked in Wikipedia == good.

Comment: Check your server logs for referral pages?

Comment: Googling [`"bytecode.ca" site:wikipedia.org`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=%22bytecode.ca%22+site%3Awikipedia.org&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=off&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=) returns no results.

Comment: odd.....it must be the website that said I was on wikipedia that's glitched

Comment: You can use [Wikipedia's external links search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:LinkSearch) to find links to your (or any) site on Wikipedia. For details, see the [documentation](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Linksearch).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen In the interest of making this (and other) referrer research solutions available, I've added a [community wiki answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/how-do-i-see-what-pages-on-the-internet-link-to-my-site/13817#13817) to the linked duplicate Q/A - you are welcome to add to this answer.