# How to find out the domains that 301 redirect to my website?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

How can I find out what domains are 301 redirected to my website?

For example if `a.com`, `b.com`, and `c.com` are 301 redirected to my website, then how can I know the list of `a.com`, `b.com`, and `c.com`?

Answer (score -1):

You'll be willing to read this → [How do I see what pages on the internet link to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/how-do-i-see-what-pages-on-the-internet-link-to-my-site)

- The most reliable way is from the web-server logs. By referrer field. But keep in mind that this field (1) can be cleared and (2) it will not disclose the HTTP code. So you can't filter out only 301 redirects. That's to the best of my knowledge.
- The next semi-reliable way is to use Google Analytics or Google Search Console as mentioned already. Reliability is lower since it won't show you data about the users with Ad blocking software.

Comment: The referrer field is completely useless for discovering redirects.   Browsers never put the redirecting URL into the referrer field.   Because of this, neither server logs nor Google Analytics will be any help in their referrer reports.